# What quadrant this equation does not pass

Tags: linear-algebra

We have Ax + By + C = 0
Where A < 0 , C < 0 and B > 0

What quadrant this equation does not pass.

Since x is in different sign than y, then the line for sure pass through 2nd and fourth quadrant because whenever x is positive y must be negative and vice versa.

Now, since C does not equal 0, the line does not pass through origin (0,0) so there must be a third quadrant.

I could not figure it out.

Comment: Look where it cuts the axes x=0, and y=0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try a simple example, like $A=C=-1$ and $B=1$. The line is $-x+y-1=0$. Can you draw this line? Which quadrants does it pass? Looking at where it intersects the $x$- and $y$- axes, can you generalize to all lines of the form you wrote?

Comment: I see, it will pass through all quadrant except the fourth one. But can we generalize this by taking only one example of A,C and B?

Comment: Yes, think about what the line looks line for other values of $A,C,B$. Where does it intersect the $x$- and $y$- axes (relative to the origin $(0,0)$)?